# Why does the Eevee rendering create alpha squares where there should be a model?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

So, I was using Eevee's bloom effect to make a light grid, with a transparent background, exporting to the DPX format (10-bit, RGBA,) and when I rendered I got these alpha squares at the bottom.  Is there a reason for this?  Here is the image;  [image: Image of Eevee alpha squares]

Comment: (It's an early light square.)

Comment: Didn't you mess up something in the Compositor Editor or in the material's Blend Mode?